# I can't add multiple swing components to jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm creating this simple GUI with Swing, but I can't add multiple Swing components. If I add a component with `frame.getContentPane().add(component)`, and there already is a component added, it hides the first component and displays the second. I'm new to Swing and don't know how to fix this problem. I've tried reversing the order of the adding, but it still showed only the second component added. Here's some of my code:

```java
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Title");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
JLabel headerHTML = new JLabel("<html><h1 style='font-size: 50px; border-bottom: 2px solid black'>Header</h1></html>");
ImageIcon logoImage = new ImageIcon("img/logo.png");
JLabel logo = new JLabel(logoImage);
frame.getContentPane().add(headerHTML);
frame.getContentPane().add(logo);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

That displays the `logo` JLabel but not the `headerHTML` JLabel. How can I display both JLabels in order?

Comment: *How can I display both JLabels in order?* - define "order"?

Comment: @camickr the order that they were added to the jframe

Comment: So what does that mean? Do you want them displayed on a single row from left to right? Or you want them in a vertical column from top to bottom? Or you want them displayed diagonally? Read the `Layout Manager` tutorial. Depending on how you want the components displayed you use a different layout manger. The tutorial will help you decide which layout manager to use. Each panel you create can have a different layout manager.

Answer (score 1):

As @bear mentioned, you’d want to add using the

```
frame.add(JComponent component);
```

Method. However, you shouldn’t be trying to add JLabels and other JComponents directly to a frame. Rather, you’d want to add a JPanel to the frame: Firstly, set a layout for the panel and add JComponents to the panel. Then you’d add the panel to the frame (see below). The reason a Layout is used is because it minimizes the amount of bugs you’ll encounter. Here’s a link to Layout managers in Swing: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Once you’ve found a layout you like, you can research more into it.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new Layout()) //whatever layout you choose
panel.add(...) //add your JComponents
frame.add(panel);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

EDIT: As @camickr notes, JComponents can be added directly to a frame, however, the frame utilizes a JPanel with a BorderLayout layout as its content. So, when invoking the add() method, the BorderLayout will place the component in the center. Invoking the add() method twice won’t work as 2 JComponents were requested to be in the center

Comment: *you shouldn’t be trying to add JLabels and other JComponents directly to a frame.* - sure you can. The content pane of a JFrame is a JPanel using a BorderLayout. The issue is that you can't add two components to the "CENTER" of the BorderLayout. You can just use `frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout())` is that is the desired layout manager of the frame. If you want to create a new "content pane" then you should use `frame.setContentPane()` to replace the default content pane.

Comment: @camickr Ah I see, I will edit my answer

Answer (score -3):

just add this line before adding your label, image components.

**frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());**

frame.getContentPane().add(headerHTML);
frame.getContentPane().add(logo);

Read about default layout for window frame and panel. Try to set null and use border properties to place your components in particular x,y

Comment: (1-) for the suggestion so use a null layout. Don't do that. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Also, why do you keep using `getContentPane()`? That is unnecessary.

Comment: Question answered in simplest way without modifying existing code completely. IMO, Malachi Parker seems new learner. Hence suggested to try setBorder() method to understand Frame and placing components on frame. I hoped Malachi will go through documentation about other layouts too and learn slowly.

Comment: Minus one for the same reason as cited by @camickr. By the time a programmer has the competence to layout the components of a frame sensibly, they'd have realised that a) the vast majority of layouts can be achieved using standard layouts, or combinations of them b) that there are some 3rd party layouts that cover the gaps in the standard layouts and c) that (truly) custom layout logic is better encapsulated in a custom layout manager. -- `null` layouts are not something to even mention to newbies, as they see it as the 'easy' way out, without understanding the many pitfalls.

Comment: I never said anything about using a Border. That can be a good tool to help with layouts to see exactly what space is occupied by a panel. My comment was about a null layout and placing components at an particular x/y location. Also note I made a typo. The word "so use" should have been "to use" (in case that clarifies my comment).